# Is Object[] $1d = { new Object[0]; } considered a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

Given that a 2D-array in Java is just a 1D-array that contains another array, is it correct that `Object[] 1d = { new Object[0]; }` is a 2D-array? If so, why I can't do like this?

```
   Object[] $1d = { new Object[0] };
   Object[][] $2d = $1d; // compiler error
```

**Edited**
Sorry, variable names were picked just for convenience. Changed that

Comment: You have initialized a 1d array; you haven't in any sense assigned an array to an element of another array.

Comment: First, your variable name 1d and 2d are invalid name(it must start by character or _ or $). For d1, it is a 1d array that first case contain an array (acceptable because d1 is an Object array so it accept any type of Object including another array). To be sure execute this test : System.out.println(d1 instanceof Object[]);   // true  System.out.println(d1 instanceof Object[][]);  //false

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are small syntactic issues and your code doesn't compile anyway. That said, when fixed:

```java
Object[] d = { new Object[0] };
Object[][] dd = d; // compiler error
```

The compiler error on line 2 is there because the compiler does not know that `d` is a 2D array. You declared it as a 1D array, you know it's actually a 2D array, but the compiler cannot possibly know. If you want the assignment to work, you need the `d` array to also be declared as `Object[][]`. That way the compiler knows and can always prove the variable is a "2D" array.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct at all.

First, `1d` and `2d` are double literals and as such they are not correct Java identifiers and must be corrected.

Next, assuming that appropriate variable names are used:

```java
Object[] d1 = {new Object[1]};
Object[] arr = (Object[]) d1[0]; // casting is needed
System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[])(d1[0]))); // casting is needed
// output: [null]
System.out.println(arr[0]);
// output: null
```

Here `d1` is declared an array of any objects, not necessarily the `Object[]`.  And even if `d1` does not contain any other non-array objects, its content is considered by the compiler to be a plain `Object`.  If it is needed to treat `d1` as an array, explicit casting is needed as shown above.

Thus, declaration `Object[][] d2 = d1;` is obviously incorrect because the compiler is "unaware" that the contents of `Object[]` is another array.

Moreover, even explicit casting will not succeed `Object[][] d2 = (Object[][]) d1;` and `ClassCastException` is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [[Ljava.lang.Object; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [[Ljava.lang.Object; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')